# Setup Linux for Putty

Tags: ssh, nat, vmware-workstation, putty

I installed Ubuntu in [VMWare Workstation 7](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_workstation/7_0). My Host (Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2) and Guest machine is connected using NAT connection. Now I want to connect Guest OS (Ubuntu) with [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), installed in my Host OS, using SSH connection. What settings I have to do in Ubuntu, Vista and Putty?

**--Edit--**
As per [sreimer's instruction](https://serverfault.com/questions/248675/setup-linux-for-putty/248679#248679) I installed `openssh-server`. Now when I am trying to connect using putty, same error is occured:

> Putty Fatal Error - Network error :
>   Connection refused

Comment: Try changing the guest adapter to bridged instead of NAT. Bridged will make the host&guest appear on the same subnet. NAT places the guest on a different subnet, like it's behind another router. You can try to configure the VMWare NAT to accept the putty connection from your subnet, but bridged is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install openssh-server on Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You should then be able to ssh from Windows (Putty) using the default settings

Comment: I installed `openssh-server`. Now when I am trying to connect using putty, same error is occured: `Putty Fatal Error - (Network error : Connection refused)`.

Comment: check to see if the ssh daemon is running with `ps aux | grep sshd`. If not, run `/etc/init.d/ssh start`

Answer (score 1):

Does $'sudo netstat -nlpt' show sshd running on port 22 ?
Did you start the sshd service with $'sudo initctl start ssh'

Answer (score 0):

You have to have ssh service running after you install the openssh-server. Some times it will not start the service.